# How to tell if a Google Login user has a default profile picture or a custom one

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-signin, google-oauth

With Google [requiring everyone to migrate](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/quick-migration-guide) from Google+ sign-in to their native "Google Sign-in" a few changes haven't been properly documented.

In the Google+ sign-in flow you can make a request to get their profile picture and whilst the URL will always be unique there is an "isDefault" field to inform a service if the user has added a custom image.

With the new process the image is included in the token custom data returned if the application has requested the "profile" scope. However there's no obvious way this time to tell if the image is a user-uploaded item or a default. Even image recognition techniques will not work, as the background can be different colours and will include a letter of the user's first initial.

Is there a similar "isDefault" flag buried in some other request one can make?

I am using PHP (for which [the library is currently poorly documented](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/standard_parameters)) but this would likely apply to any language integration.